# How to print Entering and Leaving for a function in gdb command?

Tags: gdb

I've tried the following, but I only see the first printf statement, never the one that says "Leaving".  Is this possible?

```
break MyFunctionName
commands
  silent
  printf "Entering MyFunctionName\n"
  finish
  printf "Leaving MyFunctionName\n"
  continue
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, it is [documented](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) behavior of gdb:

> Any other commands in the command list, after a command that resumes
>   execution, are ignored. This is because any time you resume execution
>   (even with a simple next or step), you may encounter another
>   breakpoint—which could have its own command list, leading to
>   ambiguities about which list to execute.

`finish` is the command that resumes execution, so these 2 remaining commands in command list are ignored:

```
  printf "Leaving MyFunctionName\n"
  continue
```